# Looking to find how to make this type of 2D animation

Tags: animation, effects

I am currently interested in how (what program to use) to make this effects of lighting and animated aura in the following [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=v8SIrRg9CSM).

Snapshot of video:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design. I think it might be worth including a screenshot of the video in your post should the video be removed for whatever reason. Also, are you looking to apply this effect to a still image or motion graphics?

Comment: a still image at the moment, and i highly doubt this video will get removed, and even if so, i have other examples to include

Comment: I think Adam is referring to years down the line when someone else may stumble on this question. If the video is removed you may not be around to add other examples.

Comment: Added snapshot - had some extra time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This whole effect is what Riot Games uses for their log in screen for a game called [League of Legends](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/). (The video is actually of a character from the game, which is why I mention it)

This question has been found to be [not constructive](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35831/how-is-league-of-legends-login-screen-animation-made) on the [game development stack exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com). However it did link to a more [general question about 2-D animation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7792/how-to-learn-2d-animation?rq=1) which might be worth your while.

All of that having been said, the files Riot Games uses in the end are `swf` files. A `swf` file indicates that [Adobe Flash](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash.html) was used in the process, which may have been used for some animations, though more than likely [Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html) was used for the animations. The static image in the background is more than likely made with [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html), some of the other elements could come from various other programs, or could have also been made in Photoshop (such as the particles). Overall the effect is really not too complicated as it is just a series of simple 2-D animations on a static background.

It's really not a black and white question, there's tons of software out there to do an effect like this. If you want an exact process only the person who made it can tell you but hopefully this is a good starting point for you.

Comment: Given the size of the files, it's most likely that it's just a video that uses .swf as a container because that's what the games are programmed to use for the login background. More than likely it was done in After Effects as those particle effects are built into AE and a novice could literally create something like this within an hour of picking up the software for the first time.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think too. I've been out of touch with Flash for a while and I'm not sure what it can and can't do anymore, so I mentioned both for the sake of thoroughness.

Answer (score 0):

It was more than likely done in After Effects. Chances are they probably used a 3rd party plugin for the light effects as AE hasn't got the greatest selection. My guess is that they used Red Giant's [Trapcode](http://www.redgiantsoftware.com/products/all/trapcode-suite/). Trapcode is very industry standard for motion graphic artists.